# Dual monitors not working - xrandr shows both

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xrandr

I have two monitors plugged into my PC, one of the monitors is working but the other stays blank. If I boot into Windows both monitors then work perfectly.

This is the output of `xrandx -q`

```
colin@colin:~$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DVI-I-2 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      59.9*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

What is the problem with my second monitor?

N.B. - Both monitors where working fine before I changed desks.

Answer (score 0):

You should identify your second monitor in /etc/X11/xorg.conf. You need create two screens (Section "ServerLayout") on that, map those screens on monitors (Section "Screen") and map those monitors to your graphic card device (Section "Screen"). Good luck.

Comment: There does not seem to be a `xorg.conf` in `/etc/X11`. Should I then create one?

Comment: Which distributive you are using? On slackware I make the config with xorgsetup command and fix it by hands...

Comment: I'm using Crunchbang distro

Comment: try [this](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=297777#p297777).It might help to find the config.

Comment: Looks like I have the `xorg.conf.d` directory instead. I take it I should just create another file inside this directory that specifies monitors?

Comment: If there are some files in `xorg.conf.d` I would recommend to backup existing one. Edit configuration file as you like and check that its working. If there no files try to check `/usr/share/X11` for default. Copy the default at `/etc/X11` and edit it. You better to open another tty (ctrl+alt+f2 for example) and try to  `startx 1` after login.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I got this working by installing more recent nvidia drivers and following this guide:
https://gist.github.com/matthewhartman/8382817